# Extract name, season and episode from tv show filename

Tags: php, regex

I have filenames like Tv.Show.Name.S01E02.somthing.not.needed.avi

How can I extract it to get separate variables like:

1. $name - Tv Show Name (without dots)
2. $season  - 1 (if there's leading zero ignore it)
3. $episode - 2 (if there's leading zero ignore it)

Comment: Because this question isn't about piracy at all.

Comment: What problem are you having? "Please write this entire, specific, regex for me" is not really in scope for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal I imagine how big big TV channels store their shows on their very legal very private servers, they may need help too ;)

Comment: Would you have liked it better if i wrote i need to extract log.id.v233n55.txt? :D And i know i asked too much, but when you need to do somt. in a hurry, and dont know regex that was my only option. Thanks again @inti

Comment: That would have been even more suspicious, Mr. Linch! You're welcome :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
if (preg_match("'^(.+)\.S([0-9]+)E([0-9]+).*$'i",$filename,$n))
{
    $name = preg_replace("'\.'"," ",$n[1]);
    $season = intval($n[2],10);
    $episode = intval($n[3],10);
}
```